# getting the old radio button on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of radio buttons in my page. On the change I want to know which button was unchecked but on the `onchange` event `$(this)` refers to the new selected button is there any way to get the old unselected one?

```
  window.old = null;
  $('.radio').change(function(){ 
  alert($(this).val()); // this is the selected
  alert($(window.old).val()); // this is the old one
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the last clicked radio to a variable,

```
window.old = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.old = $('.radio:checked');
});

$('.radio').change(function() {
    alert($(this).html());

    if (window.old) {
        alert($(window.old).html());
    }

    window.old = this;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the radio button on click(before change), and read the radio button on the new one click, code like this:

```
window.old = null;
$('.radio').click(function () {
    // Store the current radio on click, before it changes
    window.old = this;
}).change(function() {
    // Do something with the old radio value after the change
    console.log('previous radio:', window.old);
});​
```

See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/JL8V2/

Answer (score 0):

Without Globals

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(
    function (e)
    {
        var me = $(this);
        var grp = $("input[type='radio'][name='" + me.attr('name') + "']");
        if (me.val() === me.data('last-val'))
        {
            me.prop('checked', false);
            grp.data('last-val', null);
        }
        else
        {
            grp.data('last-val', me.val());
        }
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset >
    <legend> Group 1 </legend>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name='grp1' value='1'/>
        You can select me
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name='grp1' value='2'/>
        But you can
        </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name='grp1' value='3'/>
        Change your idea either
        </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset >
    <legend> Group 2 </legend>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name='grp2' value='1'/>
        Just give another click
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name='grp2' value='2'/>
        But remember, for this work
        </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name='grp2' value='3'/>
        Values must be unique in each group
        </label>
</fieldset>
```